# Cleaning fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way to clean up fragments' state?

I mean such situation:
I create a fragment instance (lets call it A) passing it an ID to load some content, than return to previous fragment (B for example). And when I go to A again, passing NO ID (it should than load default data) - it already has an ID from previous usage and my logic breakes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add your 'A' to **backstack**. So it will not be saved into **backstack**. Whenever you go back and come again it will not be added. Is this what you want right.

```
 // Instantiate a new fragment.
    Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

    // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
    // on to the back stack.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    //ft.addToBackStack(null);// Do not add to backstack here.(add every time new).
    ft.commit();
```